# Using items in a list as arguments

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Suppose I have a function with the following type signature:

```
g :: a -> a -> a -> b
```

I also have a list of `a`s—let's call it `xs`—that I know will contain at least three items. I'd like to apply `g` to the first three items of `xs`. I know I could define a combinator like the following:

```
($$$) :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b
f $$$ (x:y:z:_) = f x y z
```

Then I could just use `g $$$ xs`. This makes `$$$` a bit like `uncurry`, but for a function with three arguments of the same type and a list instead of a tuple.

Is there a way to do this idiomatically using standard combinators? Or rather, what's the most idiomatic way to do this in Haskell? I thought trying `pointfree` on a non-infix version of `$$$` might give me some idea of where to start, but the output was an abomination with 10 `flip`s, a handful of `head`s and `tail`s and `ap`s, and 28 parentheses.

(NB: I know this isn't a terribly Haskelly thing to do in the first place, but I've come across a couple of situations where it seems like a reasonable solution, especially when using Parsec. I'll certainly accept "don't *ever* do this in real code" if that's the best answer, but I'd prefer to see some clever trick involving the `((->) r)` monad or whatever.)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the code you have. It's short and to the point. Not everything has to be (or should be) pointfree.

Comment: I don't necessarily think there's anything wrong with it—I'm just curious about whether there's a concise way to do this without defining a new combinator like `$$$`.

Comment: Note that this is a partial function, so...probably a bad idea in general :)  You might be better off with a `($$$) :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe b`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Or rather, what's the most idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

Idiomatic? If you really want a function that does what `($$$)` does, the code you have is probably as idiomatic as you'll get.

> I'd prefer to see some clever trick

Oh, well, in *that* case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
class ListApply f a r | f -> a r where
    ($...) :: f -> [a] -> r

instance (TypeCast b r) => ListApply b a r where
    x $... _ = typeCast x

instance (ListApply f a r) => ListApply (a -> f) a r where
    f $... (x:xs) = (f x) $... xs
```

There you go, a fully general solution: Given a function of arbitrary arity with a signature like `a -> a ... -> b`, apply it to as many elements of a list `[a]` as necessary. A demonstration:

```
ones :: [Int]
ones = repeat 1

test1 x = x
test2 x y = x + y
test3 x y z = (x + z) * (y + z)
```

In GHCi:

```
> test1 $... ones
1
> test2 $... ones
2
> test3 $... ones
4
```

> I'll certainly accept "don't ever do this in real code" if that's the best answer

You probably want to go with that.

---

Oh, and a bit of boilerplate needed to run the above code:

```
class TypeCast   a b   | a -> b, b->a   where typeCast   :: a -> b
class TypeCast'  t a b | t a -> b, t b -> a where typeCast'  :: t->a->b
class TypeCast'' t a b | t a -> b, t b -> a where typeCast'' :: t->a->b
instance TypeCast'  () a b => TypeCast a b where typeCast x = typeCast' () x
instance TypeCast'' t a b => TypeCast' t a b where typeCast' = typeCast''
instance TypeCast'' () a a where typeCast'' _ x  = x
```

This is the swiss army knife of type-level metaprogramming, courtesy of [Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/).

Answer (score 7):

```
f $$$ (x:y:z:_) = f x y z
```

In my opinion this is the most idiomatic and concise way. If the number of arguments is varying, you can use Template Haskell or do it iteratively - define:

```
zero = const
next n f (x:xs) = n (f x) xs
```

then your function  is `next (next (next zero)))`, and this works for any nesting of `next`.

Also you can break it to more primitive combinators:

```
firstThree (x:y:z:_) = (x,y,z)
uncurry3 f (x,y,z) = f x y z
g f = uncurry3 f . firstThree
```